# Jira JQL equivalent to Group By

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to pull a report, (a pie chart or just a list) on amount of assigned issues in the last month by assignee.

Also is there any way to do an average age report, but per user as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Group By part comes from using the Issue Statistics gadget to summarize a report by a particular field such as Assignee. Most but not all fields appear in the list of fields to summarize by.

~Matt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for:

Go in to Issue and query for createdDate >= -30d, this will give all issues created in past 30 days.

next go to views>pie chart>Save to dashboard add filter name
Then you can edit the statistic type to display by assignee.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618671/1471833), you can also use a [2 dimensional filter statistics](https://www.cwiki.us/display/JIRA064/Adding+the+Two-Dimensional+Filter+Statistics+Gadget), which is more detailed.